# Android/NFC/Ultralight C - How to lock/unlock writable pages

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

As the title says, I'd like to know how to lock and/or unlock the writable pages (4 onwards) on the Mifare Ultralight C tag.

I've been able to read/write data on the tag, but now I need to lock the pages so that only my app will be able to read the data.

Is this possible? TIA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mifare Ultralight C Lock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407591/mifare-ultralight-c-lock)

Comment: @MichaelRoland thank you for your response. I've actually seen that post. Your answer shows how to lock specific pages, but I couldn't tell if those locked pages would still be accessible (to be able to write on them again)

Comment: Also, how would I go about the actual 'authentication' process? Thanks!

Comment: No, locking is permanent, but the second part of that post explains how to setup authentication for unlocked pages.

Comment: The authentication mechanism is described in http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MF0ICU2.pdf

Comment: @MichaelRoland Thank you!! Reading the pdf file, I think I'm beginning to understand the second part of your answer on the other post. Quick question though, you said write AUTH0 as "0x29 0x00 0x00 0x00" - why "0x29" (41)? Why not require authentication for all the writable pages? Thanks again!

Comment: Because that's what that question asked for.

Comment: @MichaelRoland thank you for your help! I'd like to take the opportunity to ask - is there also an authentication process for the Ultralight (not the C)? Thank you!

Comment: No, Ultraight does not have any additional security besides lock bits.